# Compressão de dados. Questão para Períto criminal 2012, CESPE/UnB

Tags: matemática, compressão

Olá, já procurei em diversos lugares resposta para essa questão, mas até hoje não achei. A questão é para ser julgada em Certo ou Errado.

- Questão

> Considere um arquivo composto por um grande número de caracteres independentes e pertencentes a um alfabeto com quatro elementos distintos. 
>   Considere, ainda, que a probabilidade de ocorrência de cada elemento seja igual a 1/2, 1/4, 1/8 e 1/8, em que cada caractere é mapeado em 2 bits.
>   Nesse caso, sendo a taxa de compressão igual à razão entre o tamanho do arquivo comprimido e o arquivo original, não será possível comprimir esse arquivo sem perdas com uma taxa de compressão de 80%.

**Gabarito: Certo**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eu diria que a resposta correta é **Errada**.

Dois pontos a considerar:

- Probabilidade não é certeza, e
- Compressão sem perda é um processo intimamente ligado a dois fatores: Ruído e capacidade do algoritmo de compressão em codificar um dicionário de padrões.

Vamos assumir que o alfabeto de 4 caracteres é composto pelos seguintes símbolos:

1. A (representação binária 00)
2. B (representação binária 01)
3. C (representação binária 10)
4. D (representação binária 11)

### Simulação 1: Um arquivo contento 1024 caracteres [A]

A probabilidade de ocorrência de um arquivo contento apenas um caracter distinto repetido N vezes é baixa (1 / 2 ^1024 nessa simulação), mas não impossível. 
Seu tamanho total é **2048 bits** (2Kb).

Assuma um algoritmo de compressão que utilize a seguinte regra como código de escape:

Caso o par AD seja encontrado, verifique os próximos 2 caracteres.

- Se o conteúdo for AD: O conteúdo final é apenas um par AD.
- Se o conteúdo for diferente de AD: Repita o primeiro caracter após o código de escape pelo valor decimal expresso nos 12 bits a seguir.

A representação compressa do arquivo da simulação 1 seria a seguinte:

```
A  D  A  B  A  A  A  A  A
00 11 00 01 00 00 00 00 00
|   | |  |_______________|_ Valor hexa &H400, ou 1024 decimal
|   | |____________________ Caracter a ser repetido (**A**)
|___|______________________ Código de escape
```

Resultado do *parsing* dessa instrução: o caracter A gerado 1024 vezes, uma representação *lossless* do arquivo original.

Ou seja, é possível representar o arquivo com apenas 18 bits, ou 0.8% do tamanho original.

Mas vamos assumir que o enunciado, ao invés de:

> [...]Considere, ainda, que a probabilidade de ocorrência de cada
>   elemento seja igual a 1/2, 1/4, 1/8 e 1/8[...]

formule esse trecho da seguinte maneira:

> [...]Considere, ainda, que a ocorrência de cada
>   elemento seja igual a 1/2, 1/4, 1/8 e 1/8[...]

Aí já não é probabilidade, é um fato que todos os caracteres do alfabeto aparecem no arquivo. Vamos à próxima simulação:

### Simulação 2: Um arquivo contento, na ordem: 512[A] 256[B] 128[C] 128[D]

Vamos usar o mesmo algoritmo do exemplo anterior:

```
A  D  A  A  B  A  A  A  A
00 11 00 00 01 00 00 00 00   = 512 caracteres A
A  D  B  A  A  C  A  A  A
00 11 01 00 00 10 00 00 00   = 256 caracteres B
A  D  C  A  A  B  A  A  A
00 11 10 00 00 01 00 00 00   = 128 caracteres C
A  D  D  A  A  B  A  A  A
00 11 01 00 00 01 00 00 00   = 128 caracteres D
```

Representação final:

```
ADAABAAAAADBAACAAAADCAABAAAADDAABAAA
```

Total: **36 bits**. Taxa de compressão: **1.75%**.

### Considerações

Nos dois casos eu utilizei um algoritmo que utiliza um dicionário de padrão de comprimento N=1 (repetição de um caracter), e arquivos com o mínimo possível de ruído (variações de padrão). Por exemplo, um arquivo contendo a sequência ABCD 256 vezes geraria um saída ordens de vezes maior do que o arquivo original.

É um algoritmo terrivelmente ruim para qualquer aplicação real, mas que serve como prova de conceito que sim, dadas as características do problema e em situações ideais é possivel comprimir o arquivo a taxas inferiores a 80%.

-x-

Uma atenção ao final do enunciado:

> [...]não será possível comprimir esse arquivo sem perdas com uma taxa
>   de compressão de 80%.[...]

Estou assumindo que o enunciado quer, na verdade, dizer 'com uma taxa de compressão inferior a 80%'. Se a taxa necessita ser *precisamente* 80% o algoritmo pode ser modificado para gerar lixo (*padding*) ao final do conteúdo, por exemplo.

Comment: Valeu pela resposta, está um pouco complexa para mim, mas vou ler com atenção e fica atento aos detalhes.

Comment: Sinta-se à vontade para tirar qualquer dúvida, @Metalus!

Comment: A pergunta parece implicar o algoritmo de compressão de Huffmann.

Comment: Eu tendo a concordar, @exp, e acredito que este era o objetivo original. Entretanto, o velho axioma que diz que 'o enunciado é lei'  me forçou a abandonar suposições; se é importante à pergunta, deve ser mencionado no enunciado.

Answer (score 2):

O problema do enunciado foi não especificar se ele tratava do melhor caso, caso médio ou pior caso. Se usarmos o bom senso, entretanto, dá pra perceber que essa questão só faz sentido quando se considera o caso médio:

## Pior caso

Nenhum algoritmo de compactação sem perdas tem desempenho positivo no pior caso. O melhor que ele pode conseguir é compactação zero (i.e. cada arquivo continua do mesmo tamanho). Pelo [princípio da casa dos pombos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princ%C3%ADpio_da_casa_dos_pombos), se todos os 4<sup>n</sup> arquivos de tamanho `n` são possíveis, e não há "desperdício" algum no formato original (4 símbolos, 2 bits por símbolo, representação mínima), então para cada arquivo reduzido um arquivo necessariamente será aumentado. Só se o algoritmo não reduzir **nada** (manter tudo como está, ou apenas permutar) é que o desempenho no pior caso não será negativo - será zero.

## Melhor caso

Considere a seguinte "codificação":

- Pegue todos os arquivos possíveis e ordene-os segundo algum critério (por exemplo, primeiro ordene-os lexicograficamente depois aplique a n-ésima permutação).
- Codifique cada arquivo usando o número natural que representa seu índice na lista gerada. Descarte zeros à esquerda.

Nessa codificação, um arquivo será representado somente por `0`, outro por `10`, outro por `11`, outro por `100` e assim por diante. Se escolhermos `n` (o número da permutação) de modo que seu arquivo em particular seja o primeiro da lista, a taxa de compressão será de quase 100%! (mas pode-se mostrar que em média essa codificação é péssima)

Não só essa é uma premissa absurda (uma gambiarra, por assim dizer), mas ela também é inútil em determinar a eficiência do processo de compactação.

## Caso médio

Não tenho uma referência para confirmar isso, mas se me lembro bem da faculdade em casos em que a única informação presente é a frequência relativa de cada símbolo, a [codificação de Huffman](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_Huffman) traz resultados ótimos (i.e. nenhuma codificação alternativa terá resultados melhores no caso médio). Vamos então aplicá-la, representando cada caractere por uma sequência de tamanho inverso à sua frequência no conjunto a compactar:

```
Caractere   Frequência   Repr. Binária
---------------------------------------
A           0.5          0
B           0.25         10
C           0.125        110
D           0.125        111
```

O mesmo arquivo - que antes continha 2 bytes por caractere - representado dessa forma terá então:

```
0.5 * 1 + 0.25 * 2 + 0.125 * 3 + 0.125 * 3 = 1.75
```

Como `1.75` é 87.5% de `2`, então esse será o caso médio se o conjunto de arquivos a serem compactados obedecer a essa distribuição. Note que nem todo arquivo codificado dessa maneira ficará menor - aqueles cuja frequência dos últimos símbolos sejam maiores que sua probabilidade de ocorrência crescerão em tamanho. Porém esses devem ocorrer em menor frequência no conjunto do que os demais (pelo enunciado)*.

* Sem essas probabilidades, o desempenho no caso médio também se torna zero, pois numa distribuição homogênea o número de documentos que crescem vezes seu tamanho adicional é igual ao número de documentos que encolhem vezes seu tamanho reduzido (também pelo princípio da casa dos pombos).